# Map lat/lon onto polar stereographic projection map based on two known points on map image

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, convert, latitude-longitude

I've searched already everywhere but couldn't find anything. I have a "polar stereographic projection" map that is true at 60 degrees latitude north as an image (e.g. https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/Latest/gfa/anglais/produits/uprair/gfa/gfacn31/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.png). I know on that image the X/Y pixel coordinates as well as the corresponding Lat/Lon coordinates for a couple of points (but not the actual edges).

Now I am trying to figure out how I can map a couple of Lat/Lon coordinates onto that map. So I need to convert Lat/Lon to X/Y pixel.

Currently trying todo that in JavaScript inside the browser to visualize a path on a chart like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataset is documented in *"MANAIR Manual of Standards and Procedures for Aviation Forecasts: appendix C"* -- [Appendix C: Graphic Area Forecast (GFA)—Supplement to Chapter 4](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/weather-manuals-documentation/manair-standards-procedures-aviation-forecasts/appendix-c.html). A coordinate system is not mentioned here but it seem to be a [polar stereo-graphic projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/stere.html).

Lets give it a try:

#### 1. Find ground gontrol points (GCP's) and create a pass point table

The border polygon can be used to set ground control points (GCP's) in the graphic (at least four) (from [GADM](https://gadm.org/maps/CAN/britishcolumbia_2.html) for example),

Create a pass point table [(QGIS has a geo-referencing tool for example.)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)

[image]

(Corner points are used ..purple marked circles)

Initial longitude/latitude based pass point table:

```bsh
  # BC Table GCP
  # NAME PIX.X PIX.Y WORLD.LON  WORLD.LAT
  GCP1    99    90     -139        60
  GCP2   368   137     -120.05     60
  GCP3   485   453     -114.06     49
  GCP4   312   459     -122.75     49
```

#### 2. Calculate corresponding pass points at the spherical coordinate system:

Apply the [proj.4](https://proj.org/usage/projections.html) definition string of to get the GCP corresponding to the [projection](https://proj.org/operations/projections/stere.html).

The proj.4 string is:

```bsh
 proj +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60
 -139.00  60.00<CR>
 -2097489.33 2412885.46
 ...
```

The final table looks like that (..see Perl script at the end):

```bsh
    PIX:  99  90 LON.LAT: -139.00  60.00 SPHERE: -2097489.33 2412885.46
    PIX: 368 137 LON.LAT: -120.05  60.00 SPHERE: -2767377.74 1600967.90
    PIX: 485 453 LON.LAT: -114.06  49.00 SPHERE: -4070468.40 1817399.23
    PIX: 312 459 LON.LAT: -122.75  49.00 SPHERE: -3749152.78 2411536.11
```

#### 3. Geo-referencing with `gdal_translate`:

Try to geo-reference your picture by these points using the tool [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)

```bsh
# SET SRS COMMAND: 
/usr/bin/gdal_translate \
     -gcp 099 090 -2097489.33 2412885.46 \
     -gcp 368 137 -2767377.74 1600967.89 \
     -gcp 485 453 -4070468.40 1817399.23 \
     -gcp 312 459 -3749152.78 2411536.10 \
     -a_srs '+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60' \ 
     -expand rgb \ 
     -of GTiff   \
     data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.png \ 
     data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000_trans.tif
```

with:

- `-gcp` -- ground control point: `img.col img.row world.x  world.y`,
- `-a_srs` -- define the coordinate system (proj.4 string),
- `-expand` -- expand from a palette define color image to RGB 24 bit image,
- `-of` --output format (refer to [gdal formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) for further info's),
- `data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.png` -- incoming dataset and
- `data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000_trans.png` -- outgoing dataset.

#### 4. Resampling to have a good image quality with `gdalwarp`:

Resample the image to an defined resolution and coordinate system here Canadian Polar Stereographic (EPSG:5937) with [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)

```bsh
# RESAMPLE COMMAND: 
/usr/bin/gdalwarp \
    -overwrite \
    -t_srs '+init=epsg:5937' \
    -tr 2000 2000  \
    -r lanczos \
    data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.tif_trans.tif \
    data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.tif-warp.tif
```

with:

- `-t_srs` -- tagret coordinate system (proj.4 string again),
- `-tr 2000 2000` -- target resolution [m], here 2x2 km,
- `-r lancoz` -- Interpolation method here [sinc(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) based,
- `data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.tif_trans.tif` -- incoming dataset and
- `data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.tif-warp.tif`.

#### 4. GIS Application `qgis`:

Now you can use your *"Aviation Weather Map"* in an Geo-Information-System like [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/), overlay spatial data and create augmented maps.

[image]

#### 5. Perl Sketch

I've written a small Perl script to get a more compact workflow and used the tools directly by a [shell call](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators) (..same like bash `$(...)`).

There are similar tools for JavaScript [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) or [npm gdal(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal)] or in QGIS more functional available.

The script and the related datasets can be found under [https://github.com/bigopensky/gis-se-snippet](https://github.com/bigopensky/gis-se-snippet/tree/master/gse-aviation-mapref).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Geo::Proj4;
use Data::Dumper;

# Find the tools in the operation system
my $toolTrans = `which gdal_translate`;
my $toolWarp  = `which gdalwarp`;
chomp($toolTrans);
chomp($toolWarp);

# Incoming file
my $inFile  = 'data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.png';

# Temporary file
my $outTemp = $inFile;

# Strip extension
$outTemp =~ s/\.png$//;

# Tanslate step to set the srs
my $outTrans = "${outTemp}_trans.tif";

# Warp step to oversample the stuff
my $outWarp = "${outTemp}_warp.tif";

# Source coordinate system
my $srcCrs='+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60';

# Final coordinate system
my $dstCrs='+init=epsg:5937';


# Destination resolution
my $gsd =2000; # 2 km

# Set the psspoint input as text
my $GCP_LL='
# ID  PY    WLON  WLAT
GPC1 099 090 -139.00 60.00
GPC2 368 137 -120.05 60.00
GPC3 485 453 -114.06 49.00
GPC4 312 459 -122.75 49.00';

# Create the projection
my $proj = Geo::Proj4->new($srcCrs)
    or die "parameter error: ".Geo::Proj4->error. "\n";

# Read the coordinate system lines
my @coords = split(/\n/, $GCP_LL);
my @gcps;

for my $coord (@coords) {

    # Trim data string
    $coord =~ s/^\s+//;
    $coord =~ s/\s+$//;

    # Next line if empty
    next if $coord eq '';

    # Next line if comment
    next if $coord =~/^#/;

    # Read coordinates
    my ($id, $px, $py, $wlon, $wlat) = split(/\s+/, $coord);

    # Transform lon lat to sphere x and y
    my ($wx, $wy) = $proj->forward($wlat, $wlon);
    printf "PIX: %3d %3d LON.LAT: %7.2f %6.2f SHP: %2.2f %2.2f\n",
       $px, $py, $wlon, $wlat, $wx, $wy;

    push (@gcps,"-gcp $px $py $wx $wy");
}

# Translate GCP int parameter strings
my $gcpstr = join(" ", @gcps);
my ($cmd, $res);

# Set the reference system and ground control points
$cmd ="$toolTrans $gcpstr -a_srs '$srcCrs' -expand rgb -of GTiff $inFile $outTrans";
print "SET SRS COMMAND: $cmd\n";
$res = `$cmd`;

# Resample the image
$cmd = "$toolWarp -overwrite -t_srs '$dstCrs' -tr $gsd $gsd -r lanczos $outTrans $outWarp"  ;
print "RESAMPLE COMMAND: $cmd\n";
$res = `$cmd`;

# EOF
```

#### EDIT: Comment Browser based JavaScript Approach of the Original

If the original image should be used as a *"Map Canvas"* for a browser based application, the product with source CRS and affine transform data produced by `gdal_translate` (`data/Latest-gfacn31_cldwx_000.tif_trans.tif` in the scripts above) can be applied in conjuction with libraries/applications like Leaflet to draw the Lon/Lat based vector content.

Examples: https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff

[image: Comparence GIS vs. WEB Canvas]

Comment: Ok so for me to fully understand. Creating that pass point table I can use any 4 known points on the map? I don't exactly now the borders but some of the circles on the map I know the X|Y as well as Lat|Lon.

And since my goal is not to show the map but to use the image and plot additional Lat|Lon on it (the same image). How can I with a map like that re-map additional Lat|Lon to X|Y?

Comment: @fkrauthan OK for clarification, you want to transform something new from lon/lat you know under the discussed parameter set, to the pix.x & pix.y on the image itself and draw some pix based stuff?

Comment: Yes correct. I have this images with a couple of known points. And now I want to draw on that original image a track (for simplicity a straight line is fine) between brand new Lat|Lon coordinates.

Comment: @fkrauthan In which language, JavaScript?

Comment: Yep that would be the best as I am doing it inside the browser.

Comment: @fkrauthan  See the EDIT modification at the end.

Comment: That makes totally sense. But to me the tricky part that I still don't understand is that Lat/Lon to X/Y translation. Is the idea to use the pass point map (step 2) and then convert the to be mapped Lat/Lon to spherical X/Y and interpolate between the two or how does that work?

Comment: @fkrauthan The JS render engine will do this for you! If the image is augmented with spatial data after `gdat_translate` step, the GeoTiff is self contained referenced state for other apps. Thats why it is called GeoTiff, not Tiff. The JS render software reads these metadata, calculates the inverse transformation and draws the stuff to the your map canvas. Your image is one layer in the map context. The API of JS renderer  from you the to provide an additional spatial vector layer (often GeoJSON) and some kind of draw definition ..like draw the name of a city from you DS with a certain font.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132691/discussion-between-fkrauthan-and-huckfinn).

Comment: As written in the discussion. I was able to use `+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_ts=60` as my proj4js string todo the conversion properly. Thank you so much for the help